# ASMX Web Service in IIS - Connection Refused

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, iis, asmx

In system 1 (Web application with web service) . system 2 (web application, web service has to fetched from system1). I can execute it in VS2008 because i can easily give web reference to system2 web application..

When I deploy this codes in IIS. I think there is no need of giving web reference again. But I'm getting error while executing the application in IIS. "**Existing connection is forcibly closed**". I think ,this might be because of different port numbers in the code.

Comment: anyone experienced the same issue????

Comment: I presume this is an ASMX web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a web reference, you get to specify whether it will be dynamic or not. You want "dynamic". That way, the service URL will come from the web.config file. You will then need to change the web.config file when you deploy.